# Hide query param values from console logs and html reports in Locust

Tags: python, locust

I'm using locust to load test a REST API. The endpoints take an API Key as a query parameter, which I can see in the cleartext in the locust logs. I know there is `skip-log-setup` that disables all the locust logs. Is there a way though, to just hide the API Key from the logs and subsequent HTML reports so that it will just be shown as **** or something like that, in the same way that you'd want to hide username/password?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override what the URL looks like when it's reported using the `name=` parameter when you make your client calls.

Example:

```
self.client.get("/blog?id=%i" % i, name="/blog?id=[id]")
```

http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#grouping-requests